# R update data.frame column based on multiple conditions, problem of using ifelse

Tags: r

It is noted that the following code does not work. But this expresses my main purpose.

```
if(df$col_1 > 2 & df$col_1 > 3) {df$col_4 = value_1}
```

Then I tried `ifelse`

```
df$col_4 = ifelse(df$col_1 > 2 & df$col_1 > 3, value_1, 0)
```

However, the problem using  `ifelse` is that the original value of `df$col_4` will be zero as long as the `(df$col_1 > 2 & df$col_1 > 3)` results `FALSE`.

The original value of `df$col_4` should be kept where `(df$col_1 > 2 & df$col_1 > 3) == FALSE`.

I don't either prefer a `nested ifelse`, because that looks like a mess, not reading friendly.

Is there a way like `sql update`, the value will be updated only where the multiple conditions result in `TRUE`?

Comment: Then why not `df$col_4 = ifelse (df$col_1> 2 & df$col_1 >3, value_1, df$col_4 )`? The if(){}else{} is clearly wrong. In R the `if` function is not supposed to return a vector. It's a control structure more than a typical function.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, you could use:

```
df$col_4 = ifelse (df$col_1> 2 & df$col_1 >3, value_1, df$col_4 )
```

One potential issue with that is that you are updating `df$col_4` on the fly, which could make it harder to trace errors / wrong behaviour. I'd suggest you store the results in a new column (could be outside of `df` if you don't want to have many new columns). I would even add a vector `df$condition <- df$col_1> 2 & df$col_1>3`. That way, you can control that the results are what you want, at a glance.

```
df$condition <- df$col_1> 2 & df$col_1>3
df$col_5 = ifelse (df$condition, value_1, df$col_4 )
```